# what transformer should i use?

Tags: voltage-regulator, transformer

OK, i am new at all of this and for my first project i desided to try to use the power from a coal (like the ones you sprinkle incense on), use a Peltier to convert the heat to dc, now i know i need 5v and i think 250 mAmps to charge a phone, thing is i dont know how to figure out best to regulate and amplify the current that will be produced. i figure a transformer of some sort because the coal wont produce enough voltage on its own, but the also would it need something else to regulate the current going in to the transformer, the coals out put will very. if i will need something to regulate it then what?

Comment: Did you try to build it and have you measured the results? Do you have a picture? Do you have a [Shift]-key on you PC's keyboard? Please update your questions with this information.

Comment: I am ordering the module still, I have examined the results of other people who have done the same thing I am trying right now, and yes I have a shift key. the example that i found used part of a emergency phone charger (the type that use a single AA) they removed the AA power supply and attached the peltier. i want mine to feed to a female usb, and as this is to learn i don't just want to use someone else's work(meaning the pre-fab device) i want to know how to convert it myself, then i learn more, understand more...

Comment: the dude that did it got 1.5v out of the peltier, dont know how many amps. what i am doing now is coming up with a good game plan for when i get it to experiment with, if i have to to get the power i will increase the heat source or number of modules if needed, the case i seen only used one though and a fondue candle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before anyone can make a useful suggestion, we need some numbers:  What voltage and current do you expect from the Peltier device?  What power (volts times amps) is that?

Since the Peltier device produces DC, a simple tranformer won't work, as transformers require AC to work.

You will need a DC-DC converter to change the Peltier output to the 5 Volts you want to charge the phone.  5 volts at 250 mA is 1.25 watts, so the Peltier device must supply at least this much power (the DC-DC converter will be less than 100% efficient, so you'll probably need 1.5 - 2 watts from the Peltier device...)